# how to pass C# form textbox value to textbox in Reportviewer

Tags: parameters, textbox, reportviewer

Im using VS 2010. I have a form with a textbox and reportviewer on it.

In my form textbox client inserts a value name Invoicenumber then when user press button the reportviewer must generate and in reportviewer textbox i want invoice number to display.

I created a parameter for invoicenumber:
Parameter!invoicenumber and called it in my reportviewer expression.
What am i missing

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you have to set up a report parameter. I am under the understanding that in code you will have to set the parameter at page init and at your button click event. In my application I was using a radiobuttonlist groupBy set for autopostback=true to select the grouping option for the report, but the code can be adapted to update a label.text as well fired by the button click event. Note that I have set the parameter name to "GroupBy". The Default Value for the parameter is specified as the parameter name "GroupBy". Hope this helps.

```
    //grouping is a radio button list of the three report grouping options
<Page Init Event>
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
//for your application set a var to your textbox value
var groupBy = grouping.SelectedValue;
var parameters = new List<ReportParameter>
    {
        new ReportParameter("GroupBy", groupBy),
        };
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
...
//for your application tie this to the button_click event
protected void grouping_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//for your application set a var to your textbox value
    var groupBy = grouping.SelectedValue;
    var parameters = new List<ReportParameter> { new ReportParameter("GroupBy", groupBy) };
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
    }
...
```